# consuming SOAP web services in classic ASP

Tags: web-services, soap, asp-classic

I have a problem with this is code:

```
Set oXmlHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
oXmlHTTP.Open "POST", "http://www.oursite.com/WebServices/ourService.asmx?WSDL", False 

oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" 
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://ourNameSpace/ourFunction"

SOAPRequest = _
  "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" &_
  "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap12=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"">" &_
    "<soap12:Body>" &_
      "<ourFunction xmlns=""http://ourNameSpace/"">" &_
        "<var1>" & Session("userid") & "</var1>" &_
        "<var2>" & Session("internetid") & "</var2>" &_
      "</ourFunction>" &_
    "</soap12:Body>" &_
  "</soap12:Envelope>"

oXmlHTTP.send SOAPRequest
```

It executes and gives no error, but I can't find any output, or I can't parse it even if it exists - but in both cases I don't know about it.

After doing the call, how am I supposed to get the parsing of returned XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the:

```
Set xmlResp = oXmlHTTP.responseXML
```

This gives you access to an **Msxml2.DOMDocument** object.
How you get the data from that really depends on the format of your soap response.

It should probably look something like this:

```
<%    Set nodes = xmlResp.getElementsByTagName("returnVal") %>
<ul>
<%    For Each node in nodes    %> 
   <li><%=node.text%></li>
<%    Next    %>
</ul>
```

See also:

- [DomDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756987(VS.85).aspx)
- [ServerXMLHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762278(VS.85).aspx)
- [Using ServerXMLHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766431(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: can u please tell me how can i parse also i mean i have done parsing
but after assigning this i cant get anything from this.
can u please elaborate further

Comment: @chris
dear
its the web service which i am going to use
http://buergerserviceschul.niedersachsen.de/modules/id/public/webservice/V4_00/rpc_lit/?wsdl

ur code is perfect and with no problems if i use xml return (hardcoded by me in a text file or in string)
but as soon as i call the webservice live, 
it does not give me anything but a blank page
i dont know whether its my Service or i dont know what
can u please look into this as well
so thanks for ur support

Answer (score 0):

[Consuming web services in classic asp](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP/Consuming-a-WSDL-Webservice-from-ASP/)

Comment: i have tried this already but i dont know where i am doing mistake or my service is not sending me right stuff.

but whatever i try fails.

this is the service address
http://buergerserviceschul.niedersachsen.de/modules/id/public/webservice/V4_00/rpc_lit/?wsdl